# React native Navigator : show/hide the navigationBar depending on route.id

Tags: react-native

I am using 'Navigator' component to manage different scenes in my react-native app.

I’ve created a  component with a navigationBar and then included it in my index.android.js like this:

```
var Navigation = require('./Navigation');
```

I’d like to be able to show/hide the navigationBar depending on route.id

I tried in my Navigation component to add

```
navigationBar={this.renderNavbar()}
```

and outside render I added

```
renderNavbar(route,navigator){

    _navigator = navigator;
        if(route.id !== ‘Home’){
            return (
                <Navigator.NavigationBar 
                style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f6f8'}}
                routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
            );
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn’t work, I don’t understand exactly where and how to access route.id

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I just managed to solve it like this:

Added a new class NavigationBar in the same file where class Navigation is:

```
class NavigationBar extends Navigator.NavigationBar {
    render() {
        var routes = this.props.navState.routeStack;
        if(routes.length){
            var route = routes[routes.length -1];
        }
        if (!route.display) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.render();
    }
}
```

In Navigation class added:

```
navigatorRenderScene(route, navigator) {
        _navigator = navigator;
        route.display = true;
        switch (route.id) {
            case 'Home':
                route.display = false;
                return (<Home navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps}  title="Home" />);
            case 'LoginOne':
                return (<LoginOne navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Add phone number" />);
            case 'LoginTwo':
                return (<LoginTwo navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Verify phone number" />);
            case 'LoginThree':
                return (<LoginThree navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Sign Up" />);
            case 'Signin':
                return (<Signin navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Register" />);
            case 'SearchForm':
                return (<SearchForm navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="SearchForm" />);
            case 'Reservations':
                return (<Reservations navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Réservations" />);
            case 'Account':
                return (<Account navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Account" />);
            case 'Results':
                return (<Results navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Results" />);
            case 'Test':
                return (<Test navigator={navigator}  {...route.passProps} title="Test" />);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use states and implement something like this

```
  renderScene(route,navigator){
    if(route.id !== 'Home'){
       this.setState({
         showNavBar: true
       });
    }else {
       this.setState({
          showNavBar: false
       });
    }
  }
  render() {
    let navigationBar = null;
    if(this.state.showNavBar === true){
        navigationBar =  (<Navigator.NavigationBar 
            style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f6f8'}}
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />);
    }
    return (
        <Navigator ref="navigator" 
         initialRoute={{id: 'Home'}}renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)} navigationBar={navigationBar}/>
    );
  }
```